# Hosting IIS7 application from one server on another

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

There are 2 IIS7 servers behind a firewall.
I do not have control over this firewall, and I cannot ask for configuration.

The server IIS7-1:
I have full control on this server.
Is behind the firewall with no ports opened to the world.
Is stand alone - but it does not part of a domain.
My asp.net application is hosted on this server.

IIS7-0:
I have no control over this II7-0.
This server's port 80 opened to the world on the firewall.
IIS7-0 has no permissions on IIS7-1.

I would like to let users to surf to IIS7-0, but application will run on IIS7-1
and route to the user through IIS7-0, which it's port 80 is open on the firewall.

I can ask for a standard configuration on the IIS7-0 in order to have some kind of routing/proxying to IIS7-1, so the IIS7-1 specific application will be seen beyond the firewall, but I can't ask for new installations.

So, is there an IIS routing feature between http servers?

I mean, if a remote anonymous user will surf to http:// IIS7-0/app, is there a configuration to an IIS7 server that will get the http:// IIS7-1/app and all it's sub folders to the used as designed, so the IIS7-0 will perform like a proxy for the remote user.

If so, what are the step to achieve such routing configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARR - Application Request Routing. But it must be installed on the forwarding server (it is from Microsoft, though).

http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting

Comment: Thanks. Have you ever found a step by step configuration for this server extension as reversed proxy?